# Is it possible to join a SELECT from one table with another SELECT from other table in a single row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

I have a table called "Studies" and it has these columns:

```
+-------------+---------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
| CodeStudent |   Type Study  | Title Study | Date Study | Place Study |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
|  10         |   Technical   |   TitleOne  | 01-02-2005 |    Narnia   |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
|  10         | Technological |   TitleTwo  | 01-05-2009 |    Mars     |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
|  10         |   University  |  TitleThree | 01-08-2012 | Gotham City |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
|  20         |   Technical   |  OtherTitle | 01-06-2011 |    Namek    |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
```

And I have a table called "Students" with the following columns and information:

```
+-------------+---------------+-------------+------------+
| CodeStudent |      Name     |   LastName  |  BirthDate |  
+-------------+---------------+-------------+------------+
|  10         |      Hug      |   Lobezno   | 02-02-2002 |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+------------+
|  20         |      Son      |    Gokú     | 05-06-2007 |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+------------+
```

Where the following should be considered:

- The CodeStudent column of the "Students" table is a primary key and the CodeStudent column of the "Studies" table is its respective foreign key
- The only types of studies that exist are Technical, Technological and University
- It is necessary to say that not all students have the three types of studies (Technical, Technological and University), some of them may have two studies, a single study (as in the case of Son Goku student) or none.

Do I need to know if it is possible to show all the information in a single row?

If the student's information with code 10 is requested, it should show this:

```
+-------------+---------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
| CodeStudent |      Name     |   LastName  |  BirthDate |  TitleTechnical | DateTechnical | PlaceTechnical | TitleTechnological | DateTechnological | PlaceTechnological | TitleUniversity | DateUniversity | PlaceUniversity |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
|  10         |      Hug      |   Lobezno   | 02-02-2002 |    TitleOne     |   01-02-2005  |     Narnia     |      TitleTwo      |    01-05-2009     |        Mars        |    TitleThree   |   01-08-2012   |    Gotham City  |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

And if the student's information with code 20 is requested, it should show this:

```
+-------------+---------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
| CodeStudent |      Name     |   LastName  |  BirthDate |  TitleTechnical | DateTechnical | PlaceTechnical | TitleTechnological | DateTechnological | PlaceTechnological | TitleUniversity | DateUniversity | PlaceUniversity |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
|  20         |      Son      |   Goku      | 05-06-2007 |    OtherTitle   |   01-06-2011  |     Namek      |       NULL         |       NULL        |        NULL        |       NULL      |      NULL      |       NULL      |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

I know there is a way and it is this:

```
SELECT
      S.CodeStudent, 
      S.Name,
      S.LastName,
      S.BirthDate, 
      (SELECT TOP 1 ST.TitleStudy FROM Studies ST WHERE ST.CodeStudent = 10 AND ST.TypeStudy = 'Technical') AS TitleTechnical,
      (SELECT TOP 1 ST.DateStudy FROM Studies ST WHERE ST.CodeStudent = 10 AND ST.TypeStudy = 'Technical') AS DateTechnical,
      ...
FROM Student S
WHERE S.CodeStudent = 10
```

But is there a better and optimal way to do it? :p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: NEver use correlated subqueries, they are performance killers.

Comment: Yes, with just writing them I feel bad xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using conditional aggregation to pivot the set of columns for each type of study:

```
select
    S.CodeStudent
  , S.Name
  , S.LastName
  , S.BirthDate
  , TitleTechnical     = max(case when t.TypeStudy = 'Technical' then t.TitleStudy end)
  , DateTechnical      = max(case when t.TypeStudy = 'Technical' then t.DateStudy end)
  , PlaceTechnical     = max(case when t.TypeStudy = 'Technical' then t.PlaceStudy end)
  , TitleTechnological = max(case when t.TypeStudy = 'Technological' then t.TitleStudy end)
  , DateTechnological  = max(case when t.TypeStudy = 'Technological' then t.DateStudy end)
  , PlaceTechnological = max(case when t.TypeStudy = 'Technological' then t.PlaceStudy end)
  , TitleUniversity    = max(case when t.TypeStudy = 'University' then t.TitleStudy end)
  , DateUniversity     = max(case when t.TypeStudy = 'University' then t.DateStudy end)
  , PlaceUniversity    = max(case when t.TypeStudy = 'University' then t.PlaceStudy end)
from Student S
  left join Studies T  -- left join to support querying students with no studies
    on s.CodeStudent = t.CodeStudent
where S.CodeStudent = 10
group by 
    S.CodeStudent
  , S.Name
  , S.LastName
  , S.BirthDate
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/SJONU26439